# How to redirect a url of a given form?

Tags: php

How to redirect a url of the form

```
localhost/website/xxxx.xxxx
```

to

```
localhost/website/index.php?i=xxxx.xxxx
```

,where x is a number, for example xxxx.xxxx can be 7234.5432. The htaccess file is located in the website folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: @AnkurMahajan, But, I only want to redirect urls of the form localhost/website/xxxx.xxxx where x is a different number, for example 4525.5323

Comment: @AnkurMahajan I don't think it is, it's related to URL rewriting

Comment: What you want is called URL Rewriting. Just google after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to activate [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

then add this to your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{4})$ index.php?i=$1
```

Comment: I made a mistake by placing the "+" inside the [0-9], try it now and it should work ^^

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I may be asking to much but this seems to work for [any number of x's].[any number of x's] is it possible to make it only work for [four x's].[four x's], Thanks